# Configuring Fiddler to watch specific domains

Tags: http, network-monitoring, traffic

I'm using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp) to monitor some HTTP traffic. I want to configure it to watch traffic from a few specific domains.

I know that

- **`CustomRules.js`** can be modified to manipulate traffic passing through fiddler
- **`oSession.HostnameIs("required.host.name")`** can be used to check the host name
- I want to check the host name in the **`OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session)`** function

What I don't know is the syntax, or property I need to set to ignore or hide sessions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manipulate the `OnBeforeRequest` function using the following syntax:

```
if (!oSession.HostnameIs("domainIcareabout.com") &&
        !oSession.HostnameIs("anotherDomainIcareabout.com"))
{
    oSession["ui-hide"] = "Hiding other domains"; // String value not important
}
```

[This page](http://www.fiddlertool.com/Fiddler/dev/ScriptSamples.asp) on fiddlertool.com contains some script samples. Search for *"Hide requests to domains except those I care about"*.